# Setting up a rule to connect two points that intersect two connected, but separate line features

Tags: qgis, sql, geometric-network

I am a relatively junior user of QGIS (currently using QGIS 3.18.1-Zürich).  In the picture below is a scenario where I would like the intersected points between a stream (each separate stream line feature is colored gray, yellow, and red) and another line feature, points #1 & #2, to measure the Euclidean or network distance to another intersecting point between a road and a stream (point 66).  The connected line features between the intersecting points of #1 & #2 and 66 is a Line (MultiLineStringZ), so each line has a different id, but they are connected (usually 1 or 2 line features apart).

The solution is to use v.net.distance; however, I am a little murky about the From WHERE conditions & To WHERE conditions.  I am thinking I can use SQL to direct QGIS to the correct location based on the elevation difference between the two points.  For example, running the v.net.distance correctly goes FROM point #1 TO point 66, but point #2 goes to point 61 instead of point 66, which has a lower elevation than point 61.

How can I use the elevation properties of the FROM and TO points layer to tell v.net.distance to only go to the closest TO point along a network that has a lower elevation value than the FROM point?

[image: example scenario]